# PHP MySQL: Why is my form loading a plaintext page?

Tags: php, mysql, database, passwords

I have tried to implement a form that changes a password in a database, however, when I submit the details on the form, it just directs me to the target page...but shows up and the plaintext code on the browser....why is it doing this!

The form:

```
    <h1 align="center">Change Password</h1>

            <form method="POST" action="reset_pwd.php">
                <table class='altrowstable' id='alternatecolor' >
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Username: </td>
                        <td><input type="TEXT" name="username" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Current Password: </td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">New Password: </td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="npassword" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Repeat New Password: </td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="rpassword" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td align="center">
                        <a href="forgot_password.php">Forgot password</a>
                        </td>
                   <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Password"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
        <br>
 <?php echo $msg; ?>
```

and the target php page:

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');


$msg = "";


if (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submit'])):


    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
    $npassword = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['npassword']));
    $rpassword = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['rpassword']));





    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = '$username' ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);


    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

        $dbusername = $rows['username'];
        $dbpassword = $rows['password'];
        $dbfirstname = $rows ['firstname'];
        $dblastname = $rows ['lastname'];

    endwhile;


    if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($npassword) || 
    empty($rpassword)):

        $msg = "All fields are required";

    elseif ($numrows == 0):

        $msg = "This username does not exist";

    elseif ($password != $dbpassword):

        $msg = "The CURRENT password you entered is incorrect.";

    elseif ($npassword != $rpassword):

        $msg = "Your new passwords do not match";

    elseif ($npassword == $password):

        $msg = "Your new password cannot match your old password";

    else:


        mysql_query("UPDATE user_info SET password = '$npassword' WHERE user_id = 
         '$username'");

        $to = $email;

        $subject = "YOUR PASSWORD HAS BEEN CHANGED";

        $message = "<p>Hello $dbfirstname $dblastname. You've received this E-Mail
        because you have requested a PASSWORD CHANGE. ";

        $from = "myemail@.com";

        $headers = "From: $from";


        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

        endif;
  endif;

 ?>
```

Comment: You are not redirecting control from action function at all.

Comment: Means you are saying in browser php code is displayed?

Comment: By plaintext you mean the validation messages from the target page ?

Comment: Your web server is misconfigured (treats php files as plain text) and/or php is missing

Comment: @Kautil I don't understand what I am doing wrong can you elaborate please.

and yes, it opens the target page and displays the whole page as if it where in notepad.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = '$username' "; check this , it's correct ? your user_id store username value ?

Comment: What web server are you driving this through?

Comment: Still awaiting an answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no html response from the target page to be displayed in browser. For displaying content you need to form proper html so that it can be displayed in browser.

In target page add the below html code at the end so that the message (validation or success) can be displayed.

```
<html><body>put your message here</body></htm>
```

Comment: this should be a comment not and answer bro

Answer (score 0):

PLease check... What is the type of "user_id" in "user_info" table... and what are you getting in user name field from your form.

am asking about this query...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = '$username' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

First $msg in target php is only for target php,won't return value back to the form

Second,you may looking for 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])): instead of 
if (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submit'])):

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten an extra ?> at the end of your included file "dbconfig.php", thus treating your target php page as html.

Comment: I don;t know, it seems like the only problem. Why don't you try like this in the target file at the begining and see what happens:   <?php
include('dbconfig.php');?> <?php   ...and continue with the rest of the code from $msg='';

Comment: th trailing ?> is optional in php and the manual advises to not use them.